# Inline type assertions that work like assertion functions in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I know what [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/assertion-functions) are and about other inline [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) forms. I have two related questions. 1. Why don't they work the same (provide the same level of assertion to typescript) and 2. is it possible to get the same effect as an assertion function inline (i.e. is there another form of inline assertion I'm missing)?

Example: I'm doing runtime validation with [typia](https://typia.io/docs/validators/assert/#assertequals-function) like this:

```
import typia from "typia";

interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  tag?: string;
}

function x(v: unknown) {
 assertPoint(v);
 console.log(v.x + v.y);
}

function assertPoint(v: unknown): asserts v is Point {
  typia.assertEquals<Point>(v); // https://typia.io/docs/validators/assert/#assertequals-function
}
```

The above works fine. Typescript accepts that v is a Point after the assertPoiint assertion function. But it **doesn't** if I use these forms of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
  ...
  v = <Point> typia.assertEquals<Point>(v); 
  v = typia.assertEquals<Point>(v) as Point;
```

Why is that? Aren't they both just type assertions? And is there an inline type assertion form that works like the assertion function I can use to avoid having to write a function for every type I want to assert at runtime?

Comment: Be careful with ["I have two questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/511366).  Either they are really just one question, and you should therefore ask it as such, or they really are two questions, and you should split them into separate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) actually [narrows](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) its argument as if via [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).  The term "assertion" here alludes to the *runtime* sense of asserting, meaning that we can assume that if the control flow proceeds past the assertion, the asserted fact is true (because otherwise there's a runtime exception).

This isn't the same as a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which only acts on an expression and doesn't have any effect on anything outside that expression.

---

There is currently no way to use a purely inline type assertion which affects control flow analysis.  There has been a longstanding feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#10421](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10421) for this, but it's not directly part of the language.

And it's probably unlikely for this ever to happen, since *assertion functions essentially serve this purpose*.  Of course there's the wrinkle that you end up calling a no-op function at runtime. This might be a drawback, but is presumably not high on the list of priorities for language development; see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695#issuecomment-518952880) on the [microsoft/TypeScript#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695), the pull request implementing assertion functions:

> It definitely would be nice to be able to explicitly assert a control flow type for a variable instead of having to cast on each reference. You *can* get the same effect with a call to an `asserts` function, but of course that call ends up in the emitted code. Still, JavaScript VMs are pretty decent at reducing away the cost of calls to empty functions.

So currently it looks like your choices are: do a type assertion at every reference to the variable whose type you'd like to assert, which is redundant but completely invisible at runtime; or emit some JavaScript code that doesn't do anything useful at runtime, but makes your TypeScript experience easier (assertion function, copy a type-asserted variable to a new variable, etc).

Comment: Good answer. Thanks. Still a bit confused about "This isn't the same as a type assertion, which only acts on an expression and doesn't have any effect on anything outside that expression.". My understanding is now, and I think your saying,  "type assertions" narrow the type of a variable at the point of initialization for the rest of its lifetime and can't effect the type based code path / flow.

Comment: Type assertions don’t affect *variables*, they affect *expressions*.  If you write `v as T` and `v` happens to be a variable, all you’re doing is producing a new expression of type `T`. The variable `v` is completely unaffected.  If you happen to initialize a variable like `const v = x as T` then `v` will be of type `T`, but nothing happens to `x`.

Comment: "Type assertions don’t affect variables, they affect expressions.". They do affect variable type. The example given in docs is narrowing type of a variable from HTMLElement to HTMLCanvasElement.

Comment: Link, please? Presumably we’re just talking past each other.

Comment: About HTMLElement example? From the link in my Q and your A.

Comment: I guess we're using "affect" differently.  In `const v = expr as T` the type assertion is on `expr`, *not `v`*.  It's first `(expr as T)` and then `const v = `. Yes, `v` will get the type `T` but the same would happen for `const v = xxx` for any other expression `xxx` of type `T`. Maybe you can call that "affecting" but that's not what I'm talking about.  I'm talking about when you actually apply a type assertion to a variable, like `(v as T)`, and that has no effect on the type of `v`. Which differs from assertion functions like `assertAsT(v)`, which does.